# Bose function convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I show that this series is convergent for z=1 and z<1 and divergent for z>1

$$\sum _{P=1}^{\infty }\dfrac {z^{p}} {p^{3/2}}$$
Using the ratio test I've found:

$$\lim _{p\rightarrow \infty }\sum _{p=1}^{\infty }\dfrac {z^{p}} {\left( p+1\right) ^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio test says that if
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$$
Then if $L<1$, the series 
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$
converges absolutely, while if $L>1$, the series $S$ diverges. In your case, $a_n=\frac{z^n}{n^{3/2}}$, so we evaluate
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{3/2}}\frac{n^{3/2}}{z^n}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|z|}{(1+\frac1n)^{3/2}}=\frac{|z|}{1+0}=|z|$$
So the ratio test tells us that the sum
$$S=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^p}{p^{3/2}}$$
Converges for $|z|<1$ and diverges for $|z|>1$. For $|z|=1$, the ratio test doesn't help, so we need a stronger test, and the integral test comes to mind. The integral test says that if $f(y)\ge f(x)\ge0$ for $x>y\ge1$ and if
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$$
Then the sum
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$$
and the integral
$$I=\int_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
either both converge absolutely or both diverge. In our case, $f(x)=\frac1{x^{3/2}}$ satisfies these conditions, so we check
$$I=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^N\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{-2}{x^{1/2}}\right]_1^N=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{-2}{N^{1/2}}+2\right]=-0+2=2$$
Converges, so our sum when $z=1$
$$S=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac1{p^{3/2}}$$ also converges absolutely. Since it is absolutely convergent, it follows that the series when $z=-1$,
$$S=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^p}{p^{3/2}}$$
Also converges. Thus the sum converges for $|z|\le1$.